# Display SVG gradients using Flash?

Tags: flash, svg, linear-gradients, gradient, radial-gradients

I'm using AS3 (Flash) to **read SVG files** and **display** them.
The problem is correctly displaying a **linear/radial gradient.**

Following is an example of a simple **linear gradient** from **Red** to **Blue**, in SVG.

```
<linearGradient id="GRADIENT_1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
x1="107.3938" y1="515.5684" x2="105.2488" y2="428.8614"
gradientTransform="matrix(0.9988 0.0485 0.0485 -0.9988 0.8489 711.6634)">

    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:red"/>
    <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:blue"/>

</linearGradient>
```

I've been able to read the **colors** from the gradient (stop's styles), and their **spacing** through the gradient (stop's offsets).

Okay, so now I've got a **nice gradient** with the **right colors** and **right amount of space** between them, but with **NO rotation or scale**, and its **off position!**.

The answer is to feed [a **Matrix**](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/geom/Matrix.html#createGradientBox()) into Flash's gradient function.

---

#### Method 1: Use the supplied matrix

The **[Matrix supplied](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#TransformMatrixDefined)** by SVG, [**gradientTransform="matrix(a,b,c,d,e,f)"**](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#TransformAttribute) appears to be effectively useless since when you feed that **matrix** into Flash's [**beginGradientFill() function**](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Graphics.html#beginGradientFill()), it displays the gradient **stretched** over the shape so much so only the center color of the gradient is visible, like a solid fill.

---

#### Method 2: Generate a Matrix using 2 gradient points

- The **x1, y1** tags might be the point on screen where the **gradient begins at.**
- The **x2, y2** tags, might be the point on screen where the **gradient ends.**

When I say "2 gradient points", I'm referring to x1,y1 and x2,y2, which are mostly telling you **where on the shape** does the **gradient start & end.**

There's the [**Matrix.createGradientBox()** function](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/geom/Matrix.html#createGradientBox()) which creates a matrix for use with gradients, but the parameters are **very different than what SVG** gives me.
It wants:

1. **Width** --- used the relative distance between the 2 gradient points here (X axis)
2. **Height**  ---  used the relative distance between the 2 gradient points here (Y axis), *but got incorrect results* --- also tried using the **distance between the 2 gradient points** here, but I didn't know what to fill into Width!
3. **Rotation angle** -- used the angle of the 2 gradient points, in radians, *with incorrect results!*
4. **Translation x** -- tried 1st gradient point's X, also tried 0, *with incorrect results!*
5. **Translation y** -- tried 1st gradient point's Y, also tried 0, *with incorrect results!*

---

### What SVG data can I use to generate a gradient Matrix for Flash?

**(Look at the SVG snippet above,** that's all the data I have describing the gradient)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to draw a linear gradient using the 2 gradient points

1. **x1,y1 and x2,y2** are the 2 points on the **screen coordinate space**, that the gradient is to be drawn from, to.
2. Use the **transformation matrix** supplied by SVG to **offset the x1,y1 and x2,y2 points.** -- *gradientTransform="matrix(a,b,c,d,e,f)*
3. Draw the gradient from x1,y1 to x2,y2.

*i.e.*

> x1, y1, x2, y2 represent values in the
>   coordinate system that results from
>   **taking the current user coordinate system in place for the element
>   referencing the gradient** (via a
>   'fill' or 'stroke' property) at the
>   time when the gradient element is
>   referenced, and **then applying the
>   transform specified by attribute
>   gradientTransform.**

via [W3C Docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/pservers.html#GradientStops).

Answer (score 0):

### SVG rendering engine!

Maybe there are some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58910/converting-svg-to-png-using-c#58912) that can help.