# How to convert SVG images for use with Pisa / XHTML2PDF?

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-generation, svg, pisa

I'm using [Pisa/XHTML2PDF](http://www.xhtml2pdf.com/) to generate PDFs on the fly in Django. Unfortunately, I need to include SVG images as well, which I don't believe is an easy task.

What's the best way to go about either a) converting the SVGs to PNG / JPG (in Python) or b) including SVGs in the PDF export from Pisa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the Java based Apache [Batik SVG toolkit](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/tools/rasterizer.html).

In a [similar question regarding C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58910/converting-svg-to-png-using-c) it was proposed using the [command line version of Inkscape](http://harriyott.com/2008/05/converting-svg-images-to-png-in-c.aspx) for this.

For Python, here's a useful suggestion from [this discussion thread](http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Python/comp.lang.python/2007-09/msg02200.html):

```
import rsvg
from gtk import gdk
h = rsvg.Handle('svg-file.svg')
pixbuf = h.get_pixbuf()
pixbuf.save('foobar.png', 'png')
```

the step `from gtk import gdk`, suggested by [Lukasz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/211413/lukasz), is necessary and has to precede creation of the pixbuf, otherwise you will not get the `save` method, as observed by [the original poster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22468/nick-sergeant).

Comment: Ah, that would be awesome, but I have no idea how to get rsvg. It appears from a quick Google search others have similar problems 'getting' rsvg. Is this a Python 2.6 only thing?

Comment: Rsvg (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Librsvg) is part of the GNOME project. Here a link (http://mwusers.com/forums/showthread.php?p=27924) to a discussion about installing it on Windows.

Comment: I'm actually on Ubuntu, and am having a pretty tough time installing on 8.10. It appears I have to install python-gnome2-desktop, but I'm not sure. I opened a SO post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787812/how-to-install-python-rsvg-on-ubuntu-8-10

Comment: Ah, okay, I got rsvg working, but here's what I get when I try to save:

AttributeError: 'gtk.gdk.Pixbuf' object has no attribute 'save'

Comment: Here's what Google has to say about it:
"You've got an old version of PyGTK-2. save() was added on 2002-11-16 by James, so it seems to have been included in 1.99.14."
http://www.mail-archive.com/pygtk@daa.com.au/msg05850.html

Comment: Ah, perfect! Unfortunately, trying to 'make' the newest version of PyGTK returns: "gtkunixprintmodule.c:51: error: 'Pycairo_IMPORT' undeclared (first use in this function)" and fails. Oy.

Comment: Ugh, I give up. PyGTK was installed with python-gnome2-desktop. I tried compiling PyGTK2 overtop and ran into multiple installation errors (from dependencies, to the final dagger: >>> import gtk
/var/lib/python-support/python2.5/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:72: GtkWarning: could not open display
  warnings.warn(str(e), _gtk.Warning)

Answer (score 1):

"I got rsvg working, but here's what I get when I try to save: AttributeError: 'gtk.gdk.Pixbuf' object has no attribute 'save' – Nick Sergeant Apr 25 '09 at 0:10"

You need to import gdk to have access to pixbuf methods:

```
import rsvg
from gtk import gdk
h = rsvg.Handle('svg-file.svg')
pixbuf = h.get_pixbuf()
pixbuf.save('foobar.png', 'png')
```

And to convert from string that contains svg data:

```
import rsvg
from gtk import gdk
h = rsvg.Handle()
h.write(svg_string)
h.close()
pixbuf = h.get_pixbuf()
pixbuf.save('foobar.png', 'png')
```

Comment: I added your hint into the other answer, in the hope that the post results more readable.

Comment: @Lukasz how to install rsvg with pip?