# How to install python-rsvg without python-gnome2-desktop on Ubuntu 8.10?

Tags: python, librsvg, rsvg

I need rsvg support in Python 2.5.2. It *appears* that I have to install all 199 deps along with the package python-gnome2-desktop, which doesn't sound fun at all.

Alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No longer relevant. Installed the entire package, and got rsvg that way.

Comment: Yup, everything I can find confirms this. Both [this](http://cairographics.org/pyrsvg/) and [this](http://www.karoltomala.com/blog/?p=551) page say it is wrapped up in `python-gnome2-desktop` and is not stand-alone. Same deal on OS X (in Macports the name of the package is `gnome-python-desktop`). There is a [package on GitHub](https://github.com/jmcb/python-rsvg-dependencies) that looks a bit more lightweight, but it is Windows-only.

Comment: You can use `ctypes` instead of installing that huge amount of packages: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14943090/1832154.