# How can i read svg data stroke in pycairo?

Tags: image-processing, svg, pycairo

I have JPG images and with inputsvgdraw, a flash tool for image annotation (http://www.mainada.net/inputdraw), i can trace lines on it that generate svg datas.

svg datas sample:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 488 325"><g fill="none"   stroke-miterlimit="6" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><path d="M 307 97 l 0 -1 l -2 -1 l -10 -2 l -20 -1 l -25 5 l -22 9 l -10 9 l 0 9 l 2 12 l 16 18 l 25 11 l 25 5 l 17 -1 l 6 -4 l 3 -7 l -1 -12 l -6 -16 l -7 -13 l -11 -12 l -11 -14 l -9 -5" opacity="1" stroke="rgb(170,37,34)" stroke-width="5"/></g></svg>.
```

What function can manage this data ?

Answer (score 4):

You can read the SVG input by using `librsvg` and then rendering it with `cairo`. If you want to draw the annotations in SVG over the initial image, you might need to use `PIL` with `numpy` since `cairo` itself doesn't load many different image formats.

Following is an example that achieves that (the only difference is that actually I tested it with an ad-hoc `ctypes` wrapper for `rsvg`):

```
import sys
import rsvg
import cairo
import numpy
from PIL import Image

# Load an image that supposedly has the same width and height as the svg one.
img_rgba = numpy.array(Image.open(sys.argv[1]).convert('RGBA'))
data = numpy.array(img_rgba.tostring('raw', 'BGRA'))
width, height = img_rgba.size

surface = cairo.ImageSurface.create_for_data(data,
        cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, width, height)
ctx = cairo.Context(surface)

# "Paste" the svg into the image.
svg = rsvg.Handle(file=sys.argv[2])
svg.render_cairo(ctx)

surface.write_to_png(sys.argv[3])
```

Answer (score 2):

[cairosvg](https://cairosvg.org/) can load SVG files to a pycairo ImageSurface:

```
from cairocffi import ImageSurface
from cairosvg.parser import Tree
from cairosvg.surface import PNGSurface


def load_svg(svg: bytes) -> ImageSurface:
    return PNGSurface(Tree(bytestring=svg), None, 1).cairo
```

I use PNGSurface because it renders the data to a ImageSurface. The PNG functionality is not used here.

Unfortunately cairosvg uses [cairocffi](https://cairocffi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) instead of pycairo. That's why I changed my whole project to cairocffi. That required only adopting the imports and one minor change.

Comment: The header of this seems to contradict the content, should the header be "a cairo ImageSurface", since cairocffi and pycairo are not the same.