# Problems with GTK's rSVG using python in windows

Tags: python, linux, windows, svg, gtk

I have a python script that works fine on Linux to manipulate SVG files using Cairo and GTK.
On Linux, I include this library:

`#import rsvg`

and I'm good to go. On windows, it's a bit more complex. I found this page: http://cairographics.org/cairo_rsvg_and_python_in_windows/ 
which suggests using the given code to hook in to GTK dlls on windows. That seems to work but glib is reporting errors that I can't handle, specifically:

> GLib-WARNING **: GError set over the top of a previous GError or uninitialized memory.
>   This indicates a bug in someone's code. You must ensure an error is NULL before it's set.
>   The overwriting error message was: Error opening file: No such file or directory

when running this code:

```
svg_file_name = "c:/test.svg" #also tried "c:\\test.svg" and "file:///c:/test.svg"
handler = rsvg.Handle(svg_file_name)
dim     = handler.get_dimension_data()
```

I'm not sure what file exactly it's talking about as I can't seem to get any error specifics out of glib. I've tried all permutations of the SVG file name in question. I'm assuming it's complaining about that file but it could be something internal to GTK that I'm not privy to.

I've tried hooking in to glib's DLL and running g_clear_error(0) in order to clear that error stacking that the error message talks about but according to the documentation for glib error reporting (https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.37/glib-Error-Reporting.html#g-clear-error) I need a handle to the error object from the code that caused the problem if I'm to do anything about it - from within python, I'm not sure how I'd get that.

Any tips on GTK error reporting and clearing from python would be welcome. Failing that, if anybody can suggest an alternative SVG rendering library that works in python for windows, I'd appreciate it. 
  I have already tried CairoSVG, which works to a point but fails to render gradients and doesn't seem to allow programmatic manipulation of the SVG data.

Thank you for your time

Comment: In the end, I've installed Ubuntu on a virtual machine - it's less hassle. 
  I still had some problems finding the rsvg module again so case any body else has problems getting this to work, try the following from a debian command line:


'sudo apt-get install python-rsvg'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why the file isn't found I don't know, but the problem of overwriting a GError is here:

```
error = ''
self.handle = l.rsvg_handle_new_from_file(self.path,error)
```

rsvg_handle_new_from_file() is expecting a pointer to a GError. Instead it gets an empty string and is extremely confused when it needs to use it... That's just not going to work. You could try creating a GError class yoursefl, there's an example [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142757/error-with-python-ctypes-and-librsvg). This is not entirely trivial: if this is not for production code, you could just skip this part and try to figure out why the file is not found...

For the problem of not finding the file, maybe try with just "test.svg" when the file is in the working directory, to limit the scope of the possible problems.

Comment: Thanks for the answer: if nothing else, this is teaching me how to do python bindings to shared libraries.  I've tried giving it just a local file name in the current working directory - it works in Linux, same error on windows. For completeness sake, I'm trying to construct the GError structre using the code you gave a link to but I'm not sure I understand the nuances of the syntax yet - I can't seem to access the member variables of the structure using dot notation so I'm missing something there.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the GObject Introspection bindings for RSVG. Install the package `gir1.2-rsvg-(whatever)` on Ubuntu. Then import the module with `from gi.repository import Rsvg`.

These bindings are automatically generated and you won't have to care about `GError` structures at all; errors will be automatically converted into Python exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the error handling working. If anybody is interested, here's an amended version of [this](http://cairographics.org/cairo_rsvg_and_python_in_windows/) needed to get a usable GError object in python:

```
      class rsvgHandle():
            class _GError(Structure):
                _fields_ = [("domain", c_uint32), 
                            ("code", c_int), 
                            ("message", c_char_p)]

            class RsvgDimensionData(Structure):
                _fields_ = [("width", c_int),
                            ("height", c_int),
                            ("em",c_double),
                            ("ex",c_double)]

            class PycairoContext(Structure):
                _fields_ = [("PyObject_HEAD", c_byte * object.__basicsize__),
                            ("ctx", c_void_p),
                            ("base", c_void_p)]

            def __init__(self, path):
                #l.rsvg_handle_new_from_file.argtypes = [c_char_p, POINTER(POINTER(self._GError))]

                self.path = path                
                error = POINTER(self._GError)()
                print("Path: " + self.path)
                self.handle = l.rsvg_handle_new_from_file(self.path,byref(error))
                if (error != 0):
                    gerr = error.contents
                    print("error:" + str(gerr.message) + " : " + self.path)


            def get_dimension_data(self):                
                svgDim = self.RsvgDimensionData()                
                l.rsvg_handle_get_dimensions(self.handle,byref(svgDim))                
                return (svgDim.width,svgDim.height)

            def render_cairo(self, ctx):
                ctx.save()
                z = self.PycairoContext.from_address(id(ctx))
                l.rsvg_handle_render_cairo(self.handle, z.ctx)
                ctx.restore()

        class rsvgClass():
            def Handle(self,file):
                return rsvgHandle(file)

        rsvg = rsvgClass()
```