# rsvg python memory leak in osx (ctypes?)

Tags: python, svg, ctypes, cairo, pycairo

I am using the following code to read an svg:

```
from ctypes import CDLL, POINTER, Structure, byref, util
from ctypes import c_bool, c_byte, c_void_p, c_int, c_double, c_uint32, c_char_p

class _PycairoContext(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("PyObject_HEAD", c_byte * object.__basicsize__),
                ("ctx", c_void_p),
                ("base", c_void_p)]

class _RsvgProps(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("width", c_int), ("height", c_int),
                ("em", c_double), ("ex", c_double)]

class _GError(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("domain", c_uint32), ("code", c_int), ("message", c_char_p)]


def _load_rsvg(rsvg_lib_path=None, gobject_lib_path=None):
    if rsvg_lib_path is None:
        rsvg_lib_path = util.find_library('rsvg-2')
    if gobject_lib_path is None:
        gobject_lib_path = util.find_library('gobject-2.0')
    l = CDLL(rsvg_lib_path)
    g = CDLL(gobject_lib_path)
    g.g_type_init()

    l.rsvg_handle_new_from_file.argtypes = [c_char_p, POINTER(POINTER(_GError))]
    l.rsvg_handle_new_from_file.restype = c_void_p
    l.rsvg_handle_render_cairo.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_void_p]
    l.rsvg_handle_render_cairo.restype = c_bool
    l.rsvg_handle_get_dimensions.argtypes = [c_void_p, POINTER(_RsvgProps)]

    return l    

_librsvg = _load_rsvg()


class Handle(object):
    def __init__(self, path):
        lib = _librsvg
        err = POINTER(_GError)()
        self.handle = lib.rsvg_handle_new_from_file(path, byref(err))
        if self.handle is None:
            gerr = err.contents
            raise Exception(gerr.message)
        self.props = _RsvgProps()
        lib.rsvg_handle_get_dimensions(self.handle, byref(self.props))

    def render_cairo(self, ctx):
        """Returns True is drawing succeeded."""
        z = _PycairoContext.from_address(id(ctx))
        return _librsvg.rsvg_handle_render_cairo(self.handle, z.ctx)
```

(from [Error with Python ctypes and librsvg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142757/error-with-python-ctypes-and-librsvg/14943090))

I call img = Handle(path) and this leaks memory.  I am pretty sure this is due to incorrectly using ctypes & pointers, but I cannot find a way to fix this.

Comment: This sounds like it's on the right track.  I tried the g_object_unref code and got a segfault.  I also tried passing gobject around and calling from there, but also got a segfault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation of [`rsvg_handle_new`](https://developer.gnome.org/rsvg/stable/RsvgHandle.html#rsvg-handle-new), free the handle with [`g_object_unref`](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-The-Base-Object-Type.html#g-object-unref). Also, if a failed call allocates a `GError`, after you get the code and message you have to free the error with [`g_error_free`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Error-Reporting.html#g-error-free).

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.util import find_library

_gobj = CDLL(find_library("gobject-2.0"))
_glib = CDLL(find_library("glib-2.0"))

class _GError(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("domain", c_uint32), 
                ("code", c_int), 
                ("message", c_char_p)]

_GErrorP = POINTER(_GError)

_glib.g_error_free.restype = None
_glib.g_error_free.argtypes = [_GErrorP]

_gobj.g_object_unref.restype = None
_gobj.g_object_unref.argtypes = [c_void_p]
```

You can free the handle in the `__del__` method of the `Handle` class:

```
class Handle(object):
    _gobj = _gobj # keep a valid ref for module teardown

    # ...

    def __del__(self):
        if self.handle:
            self._gobj.g_object_unref(self.handle)
            self.handle = None
```