# Convert SVG to PNG or JPEG

Tags: c#, image, svg

What methods currently exist to convert an SVG image to PNG or JPEG programmatically using C#?

I've read all of the existing SO questions on this topic, and all of them involve using an external process to launch a third party program. In my case, this isn't an option as we'll be migrating to Azure soon.

What I need to be able to do is to load the SVG file from disk and ideally convert it to something I can use the System.Drawing classes to manipulate.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://imagemagick.codeplex.com/ might be useful.

Comment: did u resoleve ur issue? would u whare with us plz?

Comment: No, never did. We abandoned that approach.

Comment: I also am looking for approaches to convert an SVG created in Inkscape to Png or Jpeg. Currently I'm using the approach listed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58910/converting-svg-to-png-using-c-sharp specifically using DLL's and pinvokes for libs that ship with The Gimp.

Answer (score 8):

Well. I will share with my solution to render a SVG file resized to a proper size.

I install this nuget package

```
Install-Package Svg
```

You can find the package source code on github [here](https://github.com/vvvv/SVG)

Then, you can do this:

```
var svgDocument = SvgDocument.Open(path);
using (var smallBitmap = svgDocument.Draw())
{
    var width = smallBitmap.Width;
    var height = smallBitmap.Height;
    if (width != 2000)// I resize my bitmap
    {
        width = 2000;
        height = 2000/smallBitmap.Width*height;
    }

    using (var bitmap = svgDocument.Draw(width, height))//I render again
    {
        bitmap.Save(pngPath, ImageFormat.Png);
    }
}
```

Enjoy!

Comment: this code works, but not for svg with animations

Answer (score 4):

You could take a look at [SVG Rendering Engine](http://svg.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex. It has an overload that will take an in-memory stream (your SVG) which can then be used to [convert to an image](http://svg.codeplex.com/discussions/249858).

Comment: thanks ,im trying to use ur suggestion but i get error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` could u [help plz](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414324/convert-svg-to-image-programatically)

Comment: I am also getting the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error when I call the Draw() method.

Comment: @FrankHale - Did the solution in astrocybernaute's link work for you?

Comment: The SVG Rendering Engine code does not work for me. I get the object reference error when I try to call Draw(). I'm currently using a method with some pinvokes from libs that are installed with The Gimp.

Comment: I know my SVG is well formed. I have no issues rendering it or using libs from The Gimp. I don't know what is going on with the SVG Rendering Engine method.

Comment: @FrankHale - It'll probably be good idea to start a new question as I've never used the library myself. Maybe someone else will know. To ensure people don't claim it to be a duplicate, mention that you've read this question and the link in `astrocybernaute's` comment above.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work in asp.net core 2 and the following error occurs
Reference to type 'Bitmap' claims it is defined in 'System.Drawing', but it could not be found  
and
Reference to type 'Graphics' claims it is defined in 'System.Drawing', but it could not be found

Answer (score 4):

All you need to do is installing SVG Rendering Library nuget package.

```
Install-Package Svg
```

And then

```
        //read svg document from file system
        var svgDocument = SvgDocument.Open("test.svg");
        var bitmap = svgDocument.Draw();
        //save converted svg to file system
        bitmap.Save("test.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

That's it.

Comment: When used in a loop, this produces garbage after the first file