# How to open and render SVG files in .NET environment?

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, svg, render

Are there any relatively easy ways to deal with `SVG` images in .NET?

1. How to extract all graphic primitives from file.
2. How to render a SVG file to memory buffer (with transparency)

P.S.
I'm using SFML as a graphic outputting engine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting SVG to PNG using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58910/converting-svg-to-png-using-c-sharp)

Comment: @AlexAngas that other question is closed and it is about converting to PNG. The fundamental advantage of SVG is the scalability. Converting to PNG eliminates that feature.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

please see [Converting SVG to PNG using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58910/converting-svg-to-png-using-c/58912#58912) - there are two options to deal with SVG from .NET...

Another option is http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/SharpVectors.aspx

Answer (score 0):

We can now use [Svg.Skia](https://github.com/wieslawsoltes/Svg.Skia) from Nuget. We can use [SkiaSharp](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp) with it.