# Convert dynamic SVG to downloadable PNG in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, canvas, svg, todataurl

**Goal - using the client-side:**

Convert a dynamic SVG drawing (*created using d3js*) to a downloadable PNG image and works using Internet Explorer.

**Accomplished:**

Achieved in Chrome, no problem. Once I have the PNG DataURI it is easily converted to a downloadable PNG blob.

Unfortunately in IE running the same code produces a SecurityException, it fails when I try to convert the canvas to the PNG DataURI (*canvas.toDataURL*).

Apparently this is an active [IE BUG](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/1013555/ie-11-wrongly-throws-securityerror-on-canvas-todataurl-image-png) and I've found others on StackExchange with the same issue. I believe it is related to the CORS restrictions applied on images that originate from other domains (*and are drawn in a canvas*), but my SVG has originated from the local page.

**Thoughts**

Wondering if the cause is related to the way I was generating the initial DataURI (*data:image/svg+xml*) for the SVG drawing that is rendered by the IMG element.

I have tried two alternatives to produce the *image/svg+xml*, base64 and charset=utf8, but they have not overcome the issue encountered. So wondering if it is the content of the SVG, presently there are no images within the SVG drawing.

**Code for reference:**

```
var rawSvg = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svgElement);

var img3 = new Image();
document.body.appendChild(img3);
var canv = document.createElement("canvas");
var canv_ctx = canv.getContext("2d");

img3.onload = function () {
   //-- Image has loaded using the native data:image/svg+xml 
   canv_ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);

   //-- IE Will throw a Security Exception here...
   console.log(canv.toDataURL("image/png")); 
};

img3.src = "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + btoa(rawSvg);
//-- Or utf8
//img3.src = "data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8," + encodeURIComponent(rawSvg);
```

**UPDATE:**

Tested Canvg's extension to 2d context "*drawSvg(...)*" which draws onto the canvas. This overcomes the SecurityException when calling toDataURL on the canvas element, however the draw function is not accurate enough for text rendering and placement.  So I am still in need of a solution.

See example screenshot, [left correct rending using native drawImage and right the incorrect rendering using Canvg's drawSvg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3GC7.png)

**Code using Canvg - NB: You'll need to reference the JS**

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
    cctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var rawSvg = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svgClone.node());
canvas.width = svgWidth;
canvas.height = svgHeight;
//cctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
//-- Use Canvg's extension to canvasContext
cctx.drawSvg(rawSvg);
//-- This Works on IE - not accurate though
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
```

Comment: Depending on the complexity of the SVG created by d3 you can use [canvg](https://github.com/gabelerner/canvg) to convert the svg to canvas drawing commands. Then the cross-domain restrictions no longer apply.

Comment: Yes it's a security restriction that were applied on IE<Edge. Once you drawn an svg on a canvas, then the canvas is tainted. Not much to do except redrawing the whole svg by canvas drawing commands as said by @markE, or to ask your user to right click the svg, then "save as..."->"png" Note that the same restriction does apply on latest safari's version when you do draw an svg containing a `<foreignObject>` element. Ps: this restriction doesn't apply anymore on Edge so I don't think the bug you linked to (which was a feature and not a bug btw) will ever be fixed.

Comment: @markE I just did a test on their JS fiddle playground and if I use their drawimage on the canvas element then I can produce a DataURI instance on the Canvas. That is great! Thanks, I'll post some code once I have verified it works on my machine.

Comment: @Kaiido cheers, didn't realise this worked on Edge.  I have done a quick test using canvg as per MarkE's suggestion to draw onto the canvas and this seems to allow export to PNG.

Comment: @Nicholas, yes, but you'll also face a lot of restrictions / bugs with canvg, if you do use some more advanced svg features (text rendering, filters ...). But definitely it can be an option for IE.

Comment: @Kaiido no you are right, not good enough. The SecurityException is a BUG or IE is lazy at validating the internals of the SVG and marks it tainted from the start.

Comment: @Nicholas, I'm afraid we gave you the only 3 solutions you have. Fix canvg library , write your own svg to canvas drawing commands library, ask your user to right click the svg "save as.." "png"