# Converting SVG image from Url to PNG in C#

Tags: c#, svg

I am converting svg image to png format. I am getting image from url. I am getting exception `Parameter is not valid`. Following is my code:

```
string svgFileName = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ed/Chicago_Cubs_Logo.svg";
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
    byte[] data = webClient.DownloadData(svgFileName);

    ImageConverter imageConverter = new System.Drawing.ImageConverter();
    Image image = imageConverter.ConvertFrom(data) as Image;
    image.Save("c:\\hello", ImageFormat.Png);                    
}
```

I am getting the following exception:

[image]

Following is my StackTrace:

```
at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement, Boolean validateImageData)
at System.Drawing.ImageConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)   
at System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.ConvertFrom(Object value)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

SVG is file not a plain image, you need to download svg as a file not a image.

```
string svgFileName = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ed/Chicago_Cubs_Logo.svg";
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
   webClient.DownloadFile(svgFileName, "hello.svg");             
}
```

Once you download the file you need to convert this svg file into image, for that you can use [SVG Nuget Gallery](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Svg/).

you can visit this links for svg file conversion.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58912/2745294
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12884409/2745294

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am stretching my head from last two hours. I just added the code from the links you have provided.