# How can I save a data:image/svg+xml;utf8 image as a valid image file using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am trying to download QR codes as images using C#. I know that I can't directly save the contents and that I need to collect the bytes, but how does one do that?

Here is what I have tried so far, but when opening the image it says its not a PNG?

```
var decodedUrl = WebUtility.UrlDecode(dataImage).Replace("data:image/svg xml;utf8,", "");
File.WriteAllBytes(_path + "/qr.png", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(decodedUrl));
```

How can I directly save this `data:image` link as a valid PNG or JPG?

```
data:image/svg+xml;utf8,%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%20standalone%3D%22no%22%3F%3E%0A%3Csvg%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink%22%20height%3D%22320%22%20version%3D%221.1%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20320%20320%22%20width%3D%22320%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%3E%0A%20%20%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M234.34%2C200.55c-26.8-12.97-30.99-32.94-31.23-34.49c-0.23-1.79-0.47-3.18%2C1.48-5.05c1.94-1.79%2C10.41-6.99%2C12.74-8.62c3.88-2.72%2C5.59-5.44%2C4.35-8.78c-0.85-2.33-3.03-3.18-5.28-3.18c-0.7%2C0-1.4%2C0.08-2.1%2C0.23c-4.27%2C0.93-8.39%2C3.11-10.8%2C3.65c-0.31%2C0.08-0.62%2C0.16-0.85%2C0.16c-1.24%2C0-1.71-0.54-1.63-2.1c0.31-4.66%2C0.93-13.83%2C0.23-22.29c-1.01-11.73-4.82-17.56-9.24-22.68c-2.17-2.49-12.2-13.13-31.62-13.13c-19.34%2C0-29.52%2C10.72-31.62%2C13.13C124.03%2C102.52%2C120.31%2C108.34%2C119.3%2C120.07c-0.7%2C8.54-0.08%2C17.63%2C0.23%2C22.29c0.08%2C1.48-0.39%2C2.1-1.63%2C2.1c-0.23%2C0-0.54%2C0-0.85-0.16c-2.41-0.54-6.52-2.72-10.8-3.65c-0.7-0.16-1.4-0.23-2.1-0.23c-2.25%2C0-4.43%2C0.85-5.28%2C3.18c-1.24%2C3.34%2C0.47%2C6.06%2C4.35%2C8.78c2.33%2C1.63%2C10.8%2C6.91%2C12.74%2C8.62c1.94%2C1.86%2C1.71%2C3.26%2C1.48%2C5.05c-0.16%2C1.48-4.43%2C21.52-31.23%2C34.49c-1.55%2C0.78-4.27%2C2.33%2C0.47%2C4.97c7.38%2C4.04%2C12.27%2C3.65%2C16.08%2C6.14c3.26%2C2.1%2C1.32%2C6.6%2C3.65%2C8.23c2.87%2C2.02%2C11.5-0.16%2C22.53%2C3.5c9.24%2C3.03%2C14.91%2C11.65%2C31.38%2C11.65c16.39%2C0%2C22.22-8.7%2C31.38-11.65c11.03-3.65%2C19.65-1.48%2C22.53-3.5c2.33-1.63%2C0.47-6.14%2C3.65-8.23c3.81-2.49%2C8.7-2.02%2C16.08-6.14C238.53%2C202.96%2C235.89%2C201.33%2C234.34%2C200.55M0%2C268.8C0%2C297.07%2C22.93%2C320%2C51.2%2C320L268.8%2C320C297.07%2C320%2C320%2C297.07%2C320%2C268.8L320%2C51.2C320%2C22.93%2C297.07%2C0%2C268.8%2C0L51.2%2C0C22.93%2C0%2C0%2C22.93%2C0%2C51.2L0%2C268.8%22%20fill%3D%22%23FFFC00%22%20fill-rule%3D%22evenodd%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M245.99%2C199.07c-1.17-3.26-3.5-5.05-6.06-6.45c-0.47-0.31-0.93-0.54-1.32-0.7c-0.78-0.39-1.55-0.78-2.33-1.17c-8.16-4.27-14.45-9.71-18.88-16.16c-1.48-2.17-2.49-4.12-3.26-5.75c-0.39-1.09-0.39-1.71-0.08-2.25c0.23-0.39%2C0.78-0.85%2C1.01-1.09c1.4-0.93%2C2.87-1.86%2C3.81-2.49c1.71-1.17%2C3.11-2.02%2C4.04-2.64c3.34-2.33%2C5.67-4.82%2C7.15-7.53c2.02-3.88%2C2.33-8.39%2C0.7-12.51c-2.17-5.83-7.69-9.4-14.37-9.4c-1.4%2C0-2.8%2C0.16-4.19%2C0.47c-0.39%2C0.08-0.7%2C0.16-1.09%2C0.23c0.08-3.96%2C0-8.16-0.39-12.27c-1.24-14.53-6.37-22.14-11.65-28.2c-2.17-2.56-6.06-6.21-11.81-9.55C179.26%2C76.88%2C170.1%2C74.55%2C160.16%2C74.55c-9.94%2C0-19.03%2C2.33-27.03%2C6.91c-5.83%2C3.34-9.63%2C6.99-11.88%2C9.55c-5.28%2C6.06-10.41%2C13.67-11.65%2C28.2c-0.39%2C4.12-0.47%2C8.31-0.39%2C12.27c-0.39-0.08-0.7-0.16-1.09-0.23c-1.4-0.31-2.8-0.47-4.19-0.47c-6.68%2C0-12.12%2C3.57-14.37%2C9.4c-1.55%2C4.19-1.32%2C8.62%2C0.7%2C12.51c1.48%2C2.8%2C3.81%2C5.28%2C7.15%2C7.53c0.85%2C0.62%2C2.25%2C1.48%2C4.04%2C2.64c0.93%2C0.62%2C2.33%2C1.48%2C3.65%2C2.41c0.23%2C0.16%2C0.93%2C0.7%2C1.17%2C1.17c0.31%2C0.54%2C0.31%2C1.17-0.16%2C2.33c-0.7%2C1.55-1.71%2C3.5-3.18%2C5.59c-4.27%2C6.29-10.49%2C11.65-18.33%2C15.85c-4.19%2C2.25-8.47%2C3.65-10.33%2C8.62c-1.4%2C3.73-0.47%2C8%2C3.03%2C11.57l0%2C0c1.17%2C1.24%2C2.56%2C2.33%2C4.43%2C3.34c4.27%2C2.33%2C7.92%2C3.5%2C10.8%2C4.35c0.47%2C0.16%2C1.71%2C0.54%2C2.17%2C1.01c1.24%2C1.09%2C1.09%2C2.8%2C2.8%2C5.28c1.01%2C1.55%2C2.25%2C2.56%2C3.18%2C3.26c3.57%2C2.49%2C7.61%2C2.64%2C11.81%2C2.8c3.81%2C0.16%2C8.16%2C0.31%2C13.13%2C1.94c2.02%2C0.7%2C4.19%2C2.02%2C6.68%2C3.5c5.98%2C3.65%2C14.06%2C8.62%2C27.73%2C8.62c13.59%2C0%2C21.83-5.05%2C27.81-8.7c2.49-1.48%2C4.58-2.8%2C6.6-3.5c4.97-1.63%2C9.32-1.79%2C13.13-1.94c4.27-0.16%2C8.23-0.31%2C11.81-2.8c1.09-0.78%2C2.56-2.02%2C3.65-3.96c1.24-2.1%2C1.17-3.57%2C2.33-4.58c0.47-0.39%2C1.48-0.78%2C2.02-0.93c2.87-0.78%2C6.6-1.94%2C10.95-4.35c1.94-1.09%2C3.42-2.25%2C4.66-3.57c0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0.08-0.08C246.53%2C206.84%2C247.31%2C202.72%2C245.99%2C199.07%22%20fill%3D%22%23000000%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M234.34%2C200.55c-26.8-12.97-30.99-32.94-31.23-34.49c-0.23-1.79-0.47-3.18%2C1.48-5.05c1.94-1.79%2C10.41-6.99%2C12.74-8.62c3.88-2.72%2C5.59-5.44%2C4.35-8.78c-0.85-2.33-3.03-3.18-5.28-3.18c-0.7%2C0-1.4%2C0.08-2.1%2C0.23c-4.27%2C0.93-8.39%2C3.11-10.8%2C3.65c-0.31%2C0.08-0.62%2C0.16-0.85%2C0.16c-1.24%2C0-1.71-0.54-1.63-2.1c0.31-4.66%2C0.93-13.83%2C0.23-22.29c-1.01-11.73-4.82-17.56-9.24-22.68c-2.17-2.49-12.2-13.13-31.62-13.13c-19.34%2C0-29.52%2C10.72-31.62%2C13.13C124.03%2C102.52%2C120.31%2C108.34%2C119.3%2C120.07c-0.7%2C8.54-0.08%2C17.63%2C0.23%2C22.29c0.08%2C1.48-0.39%2C2.1-1.63%2C2.1c-0.23%2C0-0.54%2C0-0.85-0.16c-2.41-0.54-6.52-2.72-10.8-3.65c-0.7-0.16-1.4-0.23-2.1-0.23c-2.25%2C0-4.43%2C0.85-5.28%2C3.18c-1.24%2C3.34%2C0.47%2C6.06%2C4.35%2C8.78c2.33%2C1.63%2C10.8%2C6.91%2C12.74%2C8.62c1.94%2C1.86%2C1.71%2C3.26%2C1.48%2C5.05c-0.16%2C1.48-4.43%2C21.52-31.23%2C34.49c-1.55%2C0.78-4.27%2C2.33%2C0.47%2C4.97c7.38%2C4.04%2C12.27%2C3.65%2C16.08%2C6.14c3.26%2C2.1%2C1.32%2C6.6%2C3.65%2C8.23c2.87%2C2.02%2C11.5-0.16%2C22.53%2C3.5c9.24%2C3.03%2C14.91%2C11.65%2C31.38%2C11.65c16.39%2C0%2C22.22-8.7%2C31.38-11.65c11.03-3.65%2C19.65-1.48%2C22.53-3.5c2.33-1.63%2C0.47-6.14%2C3.65-8.23c3.81-2.49%2C8.7-2.02%2C16.08-6.14C238.53%2C202.96%2C235.89%2C201.33%2C234.34%2C200.55%22%20fill%3D%22%23FFFFFF%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M60%2C160C60%2C104.78%2C104.78%2C60%2C160%2C60L160%2C60C215.22%2C60%2C260%2C104.78%2C260%2C160L260%2C160C260%2C215.22%2C215.22%2C260%2C160%2C260L160%2C260C104.78%2C260%2C60%2C215.22%2C60%2C160L60%2C160M0%2C268.8C0%2C297.07%2C22.93%2C320%2C51.2%2C320L268.8%2C320C297.07%2C320%2C320%2C297.07%2C320%2C268.8L320%2C51.2C320%2C22.93%2C297.07%2C0%2C268.8%2C0L51.2%2C0C22.93%2C0%2C0%2C22.93%2C0%2C51.2L0%2C268.8%22%20fill%3D%22%23000000%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M10%2C51.2C10%2C28.45%2C28.45%2C10%2C51.2%2C10L268.8%2C10C291.55%2C10%2C310%2C28.45%2C310%2C51.2L310%2C268.8C310%2C291.55%2C291.55%2C310%2C268.8%2C310L51.2%2C310C28.45%2C310%2C10%2C291.55%2C10%2C268.8L10%2C51.2M53.16%2C17.63A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C53.16%2C27.63A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C53.16%2C17.63M68.42%2C17.63A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C68.42%2C27.63A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C68.42%2C17.63M98.95%2C17.63A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C98.95%2C27.63A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C98.95%2C17.63M175.26%2C17.63A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C175.26%2C27.63A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C175.26%2C17.63M190.53%2C17.63A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C190.53%2C27.63A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C190.53%2C17.63M205.79%2C17.63A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C205.79%2C27.63A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C205.79%2C17.63M221.05%2C17.63A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C221.05%2C27.63A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C221.05%2C17.63M266.84%2C17.63A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C266.84%2C27.63A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C266.84%2C17.63M37.89%2C32.89A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C37.89%2C42.89A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C37.89%2C32.89M68.42%2C32.89A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C68.42%2C42.89A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C68.42%2C32.89M83.68%2C32.89A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C83.68%2C42.89A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C83.68%2C32.89M129.47%2C32.89A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C129.47%2C42.89A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C129.47%2C32.89M160%2C32.89A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C160%2C42.89A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C160%2C32.89M175.26%2C32.89A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C175.26%2C42.89A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C175.26%2C32.89M190.53%2C32.89A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C190.53%2C42.89A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C190.53%2C32.89M205.79%2C32.89A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C205.79%2C42.89A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C205.79%2C32.89M221.05%2C32.89A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C221.05%2C42.89A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C221.05%2C32.89M53.16%2C48.16A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C53.16%2C58.16A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C53.16%2C48.16M68.42%2C48.16A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C68.42%2C58.16A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C68.42%2C48.16M129.47%2C48.16A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C129.47%2C58.16A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C129.47%2C48.16M160%2C48.16A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C160%2C58.16A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C160%2C48.16M175.26%2C48.16A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C175.26%2C58.16A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C175.26%2C48.16M221.05%2C48.16A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C221.05%2C58.16A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C221.05%2C48.16M236.32%2C48.16A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C236.32%2C58.16A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C236.32%2C48.16M251.58%2C48.16A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C251.58%2C58.16A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C251.58%2C48.16M37.89%2C63.42A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C37.89%2C73.42A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C37.89%2C63.42M68.42%2C63.42A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C68.42%2C73.42A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C68.42%2C63.42M98.95%2C63.42A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C98.95%2C73.42A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C98.95%2C63.42M236.32%2C63.42A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C236.32%2C73.42A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C236.32%2C63.42M22.63%2C78.68A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C22.63%2C88.68A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C22.63%2C78.68M37.89%2C78.68A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C37.89%2C88.68A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C37.89%2C78.68M53.16%2C78.68A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C53.16%2C88.68A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C53.16%2C78.68M68.42%2C78.68A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C68.42%2C88.68A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C68.42%2C78.68M83.68%2C78.68A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C83.68%2C88.68A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C83.68%2C78.68M236.32%2C78.68A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C236.32%2C88.68A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C236.32%2C78.68M297.37%2C78.68A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C297.37%2C88.68A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C297.37%2C78.68M37.89%2C93.95A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C37.89%2C103.95A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C37.89%2C93.95M53.16%2C93.95A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C53.16%2C103.95A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C53.16%2C93.95M68.42%2C93.95A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C68.42%2C103.95A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C68.42%2C93.95M282.11%2C93.95A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C282.11%2C103.95A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C282.11%2C93.95M297.37%2C109.21A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C297.37%2C119.21A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C297.37%2C109.21M22.63%2C124.47A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C22.63%2C134.47A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C22.63%2C124.47M53.16%2C124.47A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C53.16%2C134.47A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C53.16%2C124.47M266.84%2C124.47A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C266.84%2C134.47A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C266.84%2C124.47M297.37%2C124.47A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C297.37%2C134.47A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C297.37%2C124.47M297.37%2C155A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C297.37%2C165A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C297.37%2C155M37.89%2C170.26A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C37.89%2C180.26A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C37.89%2C170.26M282.11%2C170.26A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C282.11%2C180.26A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C282.11%2C170.26M297.37%2C170.26A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C297.37%2C180.26A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C297.37%2C170.26M22.63%2C185.53A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C22.63%2C195.53A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C22.63%2C185.53M53.16%2C185.53A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C53.16%2C195.53A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C53.16%2C185.53M266.84%2C185.53A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C266.84%2C195.53A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C266.84%2C185.53M282.11%2C185.53A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C282.11%2C195.53A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C282.11%2C185.53M22.63%2C200.79A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C22.63%2C210.79A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C22.63%2C200.79M37.89%2C200.79A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C37.89%2C210.79A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C37.89%2C200.79M266.84%2C200.79A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C266.84%2C210.79A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C266.84%2C200.79M282.11%2C200.79A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C282.11%2C210.79A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C282.11%2C200.79M297.37%2C200.79A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C297.37%2C210.79A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C297.37%2C200.79M68.42%2C216.05A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C68.42%2C226.05A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C68.42%2C216.05M251.58%2C216.05A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C251.58%2C226.05A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C251.58%2C216.05M282.11%2C216.05A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C282.11%2C226.05A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C282.11%2C216.05M68.42%2C231.32A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C68.42%2C241.32A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C68.42%2C231.32M266.84%2C231.32A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C266.84%2C241.32A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C266.84%2C231.32M282.11%2C231.32A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C282.11%2C241.32A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C282.11%2C231.32M297.37%2C231.32A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C297.37%2C241.32A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C297.37%2C231.32M53.16%2C246.58A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C53.16%2C256.58A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C53.16%2C246.58M98.95%2C246.58A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C98.95%2C256.58A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C98.95%2C246.58M221.05%2C246.58A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C221.05%2C256.58A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C221.05%2C246.58M236.32%2C246.58A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C236.32%2C256.58A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C236.32%2C246.58M251.58%2C246.58A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C251.58%2C256.58A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C251.58%2C246.58M297.37%2C246.58A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C297.37%2C256.58A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C297.37%2C246.58M22.63%2C261.84A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C22.63%2C271.84A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C22.63%2C261.84M53.16%2C261.84A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C53.16%2C271.84A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C53.16%2C261.84M68.42%2C261.84A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C68.42%2C271.84A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C68.42%2C261.84M98.95%2C261.84A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C98.95%2C271.84A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C98.95%2C261.84M114.21%2C261.84A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C114.21%2C271.84A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C114.21%2C261.84M129.47%2C261.84A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C129.47%2C271.84A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C129.47%2C261.84M144.74%2C261.84A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C144.74%2C271.84A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C144.74%2C261.84M160%2C261.84A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C160%2C271.84A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C160%2C261.84M175.26%2C261.84A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C175.26%2C271.84A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C175.26%2C261.84M190.53%2C261.84A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C190.53%2C271.84A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C190.53%2C261.84M221.05%2C261.84A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C221.05%2C271.84A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C221.05%2C261.84M251.58%2C261.84A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C251.58%2C271.84A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C251.58%2C261.84M282.11%2C261.84A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C282.11%2C271.84A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C282.11%2C261.84M37.89%2C277.11A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C37.89%2C287.11A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C37.89%2C277.11M83.68%2C277.11A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C83.68%2C287.11A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C83.68%2C277.11M98.95%2C277.11A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C98.95%2C287.11A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C98.95%2C277.11M129.47%2C277.11A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C129.47%2C287.11A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C129.47%2C277.11M205.79%2C277.11A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C205.79%2C287.11A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C205.79%2C277.11M221.05%2C277.11A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C221.05%2C287.11A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C221.05%2C277.11M236.32%2C277.11A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C236.32%2C287.11A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C236.32%2C277.11M266.84%2C277.11A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C266.84%2C287.11A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C266.84%2C277.11M53.16%2C292.37A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C53.16%2C302.37A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C53.16%2C292.37M68.42%2C292.37A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C68.42%2C302.37A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C68.42%2C292.37M98.95%2C292.37A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C98.95%2C302.37A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C98.95%2C292.37M114.21%2C292.37A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C114.21%2C302.37A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C114.21%2C292.37M129.47%2C292.37A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C129.47%2C302.37A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C129.47%2C292.37M144.74%2C292.37A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C144.74%2C302.37A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C144.74%2C292.37M160%2C292.37A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C160%2C302.37A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C160%2C292.37M175.26%2C292.37A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C175.26%2C302.37A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C175.26%2C292.37M221.05%2C292.37A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C221.05%2C302.37A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C221.05%2C292.37M236.32%2C292.37A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C236.32%2C302.37A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C236.32%2C292.37M266.84%2C292.37A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C266.84%2C302.37A5%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C266.84%2C292.37M62%2C160C62%2C214.12%2C105.88%2C258%2C160%2C258L160%2C258C214.12%2C258%2C258%2C214.12%2C258%2C160L258%2C160C258%2C105.88%2C214.12%2C62%2C160%2C62L160%2C62C105.88%2C62%2C62%2C105.88%2C62%2C160L62%2C160%22%20fill%3D%22%23FFFC00%22%2F%3E%0A%3C%2Fsvg%3E%0A
```

Comment: In stead of writing to a file use MemoryStream so you do not have to create a temporary file.

Comment: I have updated my question with a new method, although the image seems corrupted upon creation.

Comment: Try following :             string svg = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(imageSource).Replace("data:image/svg xml;utf8,", "");

            // Convert SVG to byte array
            byte[] svgBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(svg);

            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(svgBytes);

            var svgDocument = SvgDocument.Open(stream);
            var bitmap = svgDocument.Draw();
            bitmap.Save(path + snap + ".png", ImageFormat.Png);

Comment: @jdweng Where is this `SvgDocument` class coming from?

Comment: Your code was writing the byte[] array to a temporary file (which is a stream). My code is writing the byte[] array to a memory stream.  Then using the MemoryStream for the source of the SvgDocument (your code was reading the temporary file).

Comment: @jdweng `.Open` doesn't support memory stream, could you answer the question with a working code example?

Comment: SvgDocument doc = new SvgDocument(); doc.Open(stream);

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58910/converting-svg-to-png-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the bytes:

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,%3C%3Fxml...");
```

Then if you want to save to a file:

```
var fileInfo = new FileInfo($"{dirPath}\\{fileName}");
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
{
    using (var fileStream = fileInfo.Create())
    {
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
    }
}
```